# Use `setcontent` where an array field contains a value

Tags: bolt-cms

I'm a little bit rusty with twig.

But I'm trying to achieve this in a `setcontent`.

`{% setcontent entries = 'entries' where { authors: 'AN SPECIFIC ID IS IN THE AUTHORS ARRAY' } %}`

The authors field is an array where multiple IDs can be contained.

How can I achieve this?